# How to mock multer with supertest?

Tags: node.js, multer, supertest

I'm writing file upload API and have some troubles with mocking multer. I'm trying to test my endpoint with supertest.

```
it('load image', async () => {
    await app
        .post(`${apiImage}`)
        .set('Authorization', 'abc123')
        .attach('avatar', `${__dirname}/test.jpg`);
        .expect(200);
});
```

Upload works as expected. But every time when I run test, new file being created. So, how to mock multer and does not create new file every time?

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Did you figure out how to mock or stub multer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had a middleware helper to wrap multer like this

```
// middleware/index.js

const multer = require('multer');
exports.multerUpload = () => multer({...});
```

Then use it in my routes like so

```
// routes.js

const { multerUpload } = require('path/to/middlewares');

app.post('/upload', multerUpload().any());
```

Then, in my tests, I can stub out multerUpload

```
// test.js

const middlewares = require('path/to/middlewares');
sinon.stub(middlewares, 'multerUpload').callsFake(
      () => {
        return {
          any() {
            return (req, res, next) => {
              // You can do whatever you like to the request body here e.g
              req.body = { title: req.query.title };
              req.files = [{ location: 'sample.url', key: 'sample.key' }];
              return next();
            };
          },
        };
      },
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Mock Multer using Jest (Similar to above ans but using Jest)

App.js

Used multer as middleware

```
const app = express();
app.use()
app.use(multer({ dest: FILE_UPLOAD_PATH }).single('datafile'));
app.use('/api', apiRoutes);
```

apiRoute.js

```
router.post('/datasources', async function (req, res) {
    
    ...

});
```

apiRoute.test.js

```
const multer = require('multer');

jest.mock('multer');

multer.mockImplementation(() => {
  return {
    single() {
      return (req, res, next) => {
        req.body = { title: req.query.title };
        req.file = [{ originalname: 'sample.name', mimetype: 'sample.type', path: 'sample.url' }];
        return next();
      };
    },
  };
});

.
.
.
```